Is there a way to suppress deprecation messages only when raised by specific plugins
My ISP has recently updated their default php version, and now a couple of plugins are raising "PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property". I didn't develop these plugins and I don't know how soon they will be updated, but I believe at least one is no longer actively supported.
I would like to suppress this deprecation message as it is currently clogging up my log files. I know I can do this be running error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);. However ideally I would suppress it only in the relevant plugins, so that I still get warnings if I accidentally create a dynamic property or use some other deprecated code in my own plugins.
Is there a way to only apply the error_reporting statement around code in specific plugins?
